# the difference between 1/a*a and 1*a/a

Tags: c++, variables

`a=99.0
cout<<(1.0/a*a==1.0)` give 0

while

`cout<<(1*a/a==1.0)` give 1
and 
`cout<<(1.0/99.0*99.0==1.0)` also give 1

what's the rationale behind them???
why I change the order of the variables or when I change it to real number,
the outcome will change?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is absolutely correct!
These are known issues with floats and doubles:
[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

Comment: @geipel Those are not _issues_. It's how floating points are defined and work. The fact that they don't work as you expect doesn't mean that they are flawed. Maybe the expectations were wrong and that's all.

Comment: @skypjack: You are correct that this just how IEEE 754 works. I was agreeing with the statement that use of == operator (on calculated float values) is generally problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers have a finite number of precision bits.

Consider this example (in base 10, with 5 fractional digits, for the sake of explaining) where `a` is `3.0`:

**First case: 1.0 / 3.0 * 3.0**

Here the division (1.0 / 3.0) is calculated first, giving you an intermediate value of 0.33333.

Then the multiplication is carried out: 0.33333 * 3 = 0.99999 which is different from 1.0

**Second case: 1.0 * 3.0 / 3.0**

In this case, the multiplication (1.0 * 3.0) is carried out first, giving an intermediate value of 3.0, which is divided by 3.0, giving you exactly 1.0

Because of this effect, as others have stated, it is not a good idea to compare floating point values exactly with `==`.